# When process exit, will the memory that's left undeleted be returned to OS?

Tags: memory-leaks, operating-system

I am wondering if i new some object but forget to delete it, when the process exit, will the leaked memory be returned to the OS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't so mush a C++ question as an operating system question.

All of the operating systems that I have knowledge of will reclaim conventional memory that had been allocated. That's because the allocation generally comes from a processes private address space which will be reclaimed on exit.

This may not be true for other resources such as shared memory. There are implementations that will *not* release shared memory segments unless you specifically mark them for deletion before your process exits (and, even then, they don't get deleted until everyone has detached).

Answer (score 1):

For most modern operating systems (most flavors of unix and anything running in protected memory under x86), the memory allocation occurs within a program's heap (either through malloc for C or new/delete for C++).  So when the program exits, then the memory will be released for use elsewhere.